# grails how to create a unit test

Tags: grails

I am a bit new to using grails so please forgive me if this has an obvious answer. I have been going through the documentation on how unit tests are automatically created when you create a new controller. from what i have seen online and in books, the controller test class name is appended with "test" at the end. using grails 2.3.1 in the \test\unit\ directory it created StoreControllerSpec.groovy
in that i have

```
@TestFor(StoreController)
class StoreControllerSpec extends Specification {

def setup() {
}

def cleanup() {
}

void testSomething() {
\\ added to see if the test works
controller.index()
assert 'Welcome to the gTunes store!' == response.text
}
}
```

the problem I am having is that when running test-app it tries to run the unit test but outputs nothing and it is not marked as failed?

```
grails> test-app
| Running without daemon...
| Compiling 1 source files
| Compiling 1 source files.
| Running 1 unit test...
| Completed 0 unit test, 0 failed in 0m 4s
| Tests PASSED - view reports in
```

Answer (score 1):

i managed to fix the issue by changing how the test is written eg

```
void "test Something"() {
controller.index()
expect:
"Welcome to the gTunes store!" == response.text
}
```

this is because grails now uses the spock test framework by default

Comment: Right - Spock test methods require at least one labelled block, see https://code.google.com/p/spock/wiki/SpockBasics

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

grails 2.3.x uses spock framework by default for testing

//Controller class

class DomainListController {

```
def index() {
    redirect (action:"list")
}

def list() {
    render "hello"
}
```

}

//Test class

@TestFor(DomainListController) 
class DomainListControllerSpec extends Specification {

```
def setup() {
}

def cleanup() {
}

void "test something"() {
}

//test method to test index() of DomainListController
def void testIndex() {
    controller.index()              
    expect:
     response.redirectedUrl == 'domainList/listll'
}

//test method to test list() of DomainListController
def void testList() {
    controller.list()       
            expect:
    response.text == "hello"
}
```

}

--> @TestFor mixin takes care of the contoller mocking. You can very well access some keywords here like controller, contoller.params, controller.request, controller.response without instantiating controller.

-->The response object is an instance of GrailsMockHttpServletResponse (from the package org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.testing) which extends Spring's MockHttpServletResponse class and has a number of useful methods for inspecting the state of the response.

-->expect: is the expected result

Hope this helps you :) 
cheers - Mothi

Answer (score 0):

In the previous versions of grails, the class that contained the tests had to end in "Tests". Might be worth trying that?

eg.

```
class StoreControllerSpecTests extends Specification
```

Comment: sorry no luck, i renamed the class and it did the same thing